# Gradle dependency issues android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've noticed there is a conflict between io.reactive and estimote's sdk but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve it. I honestly only noticed the conflict by removing the estimote dependency and then later removing the two reactivex dependencies and finding the project functional. I have tried excluding common libraries but nothing seems to work. Here is everything I have:

Original Error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


buildscript {
    repositories {

//
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {



        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
//
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whats.up"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 49
        versionName "2.0"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile project(":libs:library")
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.81.1'
    compile files('libs/cwac-merge-1.1.1-2.jar')
    compile files('libs/cwac-camera-0.6.12.jar')
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.0'
    compile ('com.estimote:sdk:0.8.6@aar'){
//
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'junit'
        exclude module: 'io.reactivex'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.*'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
        exclude group: 'com.android.dx'
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.7.0@aar')
            {
                transitive = true;
            }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;

    }
}
```

./gradlew -q app:dependencies:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+ -> 21.0.3
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 22.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+ -> 22.0.0 (*)
+--- uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
+--- com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+ -> 6.5.87
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0 -> 22.0.0 (*)
+--- com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.2
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0 -> 22.0.0 (*)
+--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0
+--- project :libs:library
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0 (*)
+--- io.realm:realm-android:0.81.1
+--- com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.0
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22) -> 22.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.7.0
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1 -> 1.9.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.0 -> 1.3.5
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.3.1
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.0 -> 1.3.5
|    +--- com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.0.0
|    |    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.0 -> 1.3.5
|    |    \--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:1.0.0
|    |         +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2 -> 2.5.2
|    |         +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.0 -> 1.3.5
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0 -> 22.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.0 -> 1.3.5
|    \--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:1.0.0 (*)
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13
+--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.0 -> 1.0.13
+--- com.estimote:sdk:0.8.6
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:0.7.0 (*)
\--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1
     +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.4
     |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
     |    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.1
     |         \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.5
     +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.3
     |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.4 -> 1.3.5
     \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.1 (*)
```

I am fairly unsure on how to interpret the last part there - so if my issue is revealed in that I'd love to know how to find it for future reference! Thanks!

Comment: Check multidex https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @Alntel : add this to your gradle -> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy, **NOT RECOMMENDED FIX** is:

In your app's build.gradle:

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

**The cause:**

> Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX file, known as a multidex configuration.

All the details here: [Building Apps with Over 65k Methods](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

While the answer given will be a quick way to fix your current issue, **Android recommends against it, or at least recommends you to avoid it if possible.**

**Reducing your dexcount**

Try to avoid depending on large open source projects unless you **REALLY** need them. If you can't avoid these, use them in a smart way. Some libraries like `GooglePlayServices` offer you to consume a subset of their API to prevent this type of issues.

Example, you have:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+ // The ENTIRE play-services library
```

Do you really need the entire play-services library? That library is huge and Google provides you means of using just the components you need, say you want to use Google Account Login, you can have as follows instead:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:X.+ // Google Account Login only
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:X.+ // Google Analytics
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:X.+ // Google Maps...
// ... and so on.
```

For the list of individual APIs for play-services see [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

**Tracking your dexcount**

There's several libraries that can help you track your dexcount as a way to prevent you from reaching the limit. An example:

[Dexcount Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin)

This library will keep track of your dexcount and report it while you build, e.g.:

```
> ./gradlew assembleDebug

...buildspam...
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug
Total methods in MyApp-debug-5.3.14.apk: 56538
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
```

in your **defaultConfig**
and add this

```
 dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html